# time series of daily degree day using ERA 5 hourly data in earth engine for multiple points

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

i am a newbie EE user, hope anyone could help me here
i tried to extract the degree day time series of multiple points using ERA 5 hourly. i tried modifying the snippet on [Calculating daily GDD from ERA-5 Hourly data](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/429837/calculating-daily-gdd-from-era-5-hourly-data) but i got lost. the output i want to get is a csv with column of 'id','kelas','gddvalue 2018-01-01','gddvalue 2018-01-02','gddvalue 2018-01-03','gddvalue 2018-01-04', ..., so on
my "points1" is a featurecollection in asset

```
// Define points of interest
var points = points1.select(['id','kelas']).sort('id');
var startdate =ee.Date.fromYMD(2018,01,01,'Asia/Jakarta')
var enddate = ee.Date.fromYMD(2023,01,01,'Asia/Jakarta')
// Define image collection
var collection = ee.ImageCollection("ECMWF/ERA5_LAND/HOURLY")
            .filter(ee.Filter.date(startdate,enddate))
            .filterBounds(points)
            .select('temperature_2m');

// Define function to calculate GDD
var cgdd = function(image){
      var min = image.min()
      var min1 = min.clip(points)
      //Map.addLayer(min1,{},'min1')
      var max = image.max()
      var max1 = max.clip(points)
      //Map.addLayer(max1,{},'max1')
      var a = ee.Image(2)
      var sum = max1.add(min1)
      var avg = sum.divide(a)
      var b = ee.Image(273)
     var celcius= avg.subtract(b)
     //Map.addLayer(avg,{},'avg')
     //Map.addLayer(celcius,{},'celcius')
     var c = ee.Image(17)
     var gdd = celcius.subtract(c).rename('GDD');  
//Map.addLayer(gdd,{},'gdd')
  return gdd;
  };

// Map the function over the image collection
var gddCollection = collection.map(cgdd);

// Define the time zone
var timeZone = 'UTC+7';

// Reduce the image collection to a table
var table = gddCollection.reduceRegions({
  collection: points,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  scale: 10
});

// Format the date and time in the desired time zone
table = table.map(function(feature) {
  var date = ee.Date(feature.get('system:time_start'));
  var dateString = date.format('YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss', timeZone);
  return feature.set('date', dateString);
});

// Print the table
print(table);

// Export the table to CSV
Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: table,
  description: 'GDD_points',
  folder: 'GEE',
  fileNamePrefix: 'GDD_points',
  fileFormat: 'CSV'
});
```